# SSD1306 OLED LCD Library Errors

Tags: arduino-due, lcd, library

Recently i bought an "Serial 128X64 OLED LCD Display SSD1306".

I searched for available libraries and tried to find the best one to use before actually experimenting with this device.

I came across a hackaday article mentioning a "HIGH SPEED SSD1306 LIBRARY"

So that drew my attention and got on with it. This is the link to the afforementioned library for the Arduino DUE.

[DayOLED_SSD1306](https://github.com/GravCorp/DayOLED_SSD1306)

Right from the beginning i had some trouble with the wiring.
I wired 3.3 volts to input, GND, RES, DC, CS pins are wired according to the library example..
But the library contains no info on how to wire D0 and D1 pins. Since this OLED works both I2C and SPI, i thought maybe these two pins are ommited.

So i hooked it up, load up the example code and got compilation errors.

Here are the errors:

```
C:\Users\User1\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DayOLED_SSD1306-master\DayOLED_SSD1306.cpp: In member function 'virtual void DayOLED_SSD1306::drawPixel(int16_t, int16_t, uint16_t)':

C:\Users\User1\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DayOLED_SSD1306-master\DayOLED_SSD1306.cpp:114:14: error: 'swap' was not declared in this scope

     swap(x, y);

              ^

C:\Users\User1\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DayOLED_SSD1306-master\DayOLED_SSD1306.cpp: In member function 'virtual void DayOLED_SSD1306::drawFastHLine(int16_t, int16_t, int16_t, uint16_t)':

C:\Users\User1\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DayOLED_SSD1306-master\DayOLED_SSD1306.cpp:598:16: error: 'swap' was not declared in this scope

       swap(x, y);

                ^

C:\Users\User1\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DayOLED_SSD1306-master\DayOLED_SSD1306.cpp: In member function 'virtual void DayOLED_SSD1306::drawFastVLine(int16_t, int16_t, int16_t, uint16_t)':

C:\Users\User1\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DayOLED_SSD1306-master\DayOLED_SSD1306.cpp:666:16: error: 'swap' was not declared in this scope

       swap(x, y);
```

Anybody got a clue what is going on with the swap() function?
Maybe it's deprecated?

Anyone has managed to get this library working?
Or maybe has managed to get this Display working even with another library?

Answer (score 1):

I've had good success with the u8g2 library for the small I2C OLEDs. 
[u8g2 on GitHub](https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2)

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get this somewhat working with these 4 libraries:
#include <SPI.h>,
#include <Wire.h>,
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>,
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>.
These should all be in the include library in the ide.
Hope this helps!